# Mix byte array android

Tags: java, android

I would like to mix audio byte array, but I didn't succeed to sum the array.(note i already added some silent bytes of 0 as padding before).
I have an `ArrayList` of `byte[]` which contains:

- the first byte[] is header (44 bytes).
- Following byte[] are raw data byte array to be mixed

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> ListAudio = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
byte[] header= WriteHeader(); //wav header 44 bytes
ListAudio.add(header);
for (byte[] b : audioTreatment.ListDataByte) {
      ListAudio.add(b);
 }
 //calculate total length of audio
 int length = 0;
 for (byte[] array : ListAudio) {
 length += array.length;
 }

 final int len = length;
 final byte[] mixBytes = new byte[len];
 for (byte[] array : ListAudio) {
 for (int i = 44; i < len; ++i) {
     mixBytes[i] += array[i];
   // mixBytes[i]=(byte) ((bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]) / 2);

     }
}
```

I found somewhere that the method to mix digital byte array is :

```
mixBytes[i]=(byte) ((bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]) / 2);
```

I don't arrive to include the calcul above, to sum the byte array.
How can i sum the bytes array from my ArrayList ?

Comment: uhm, what was the question?

Comment: Martin Frank, i edited my question, thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare your sources to merge them

```
byte[] source1 = ListAudio.get(0); //first from list
byte[] source2 = ListAudio.get(1); //second from list

int length = Math.min(source1.length, source2.length);//length of new array
length = length - 44; //skipping 44 byte

byte[] dest = new byte[length];
for(int index = 0; index < length; index ++){
    byte b1 = source1[index+44];
    byte b2 = source2[index+44];
    dest[index] = (byte) ((b1+b2) / 2);
}
```

That would merge the first two byte[] from your list.

If you want to merge other sources you can change them by selecting other `byte[]` from your List.

*HINT*
The length of the destination is declared as `Math.min(a,b)` but you can fill missing bytes with zeros if you want...

if you want to merge **all** arrays, you have to adjust your merge operation

mixing *two* bytes: `mixBytes[i]=(byte) ((bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]) / 2);`

mixing *three* bytes: `mixBytes[i]=(byte) ((bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]+bytes3[i]) / 3);`

mixing *N* bytes: `mixBytes[i]=(byte) ((bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]+bytes3[i]+...+bytesN[i]) / N);`

ok, for your code snipped it would be:

```
int length = ...;//length of result, either min or max as mentioned above, see HINT
byte[] mixBytes = new byte[length]; 

int amountAudio = ListAudio.size(); //amount of tracks in your list aka 'N' 

int sum;
for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
    sum = 0;
    for(byte[] source: ListAudio){
        //adding all byte into one big integer
        sum = sum + source[index]; //NOTE: watch for indexOutOfBoundsException
    }
    //afterward divide the big int through amount of Audio tracks in your list
    mixBytes[index] = (byte)(sum / amountAudio);
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if the conversion (`(byte1+byte2)/2`)is working properly, I copy/pastd it from your code

Comment: Thanks you very much, but if my source within the arraylist are dynamic and i can't declare them statically, how could i proceed?

Comment: uhm - i'm not sure what you mean... what is dynamically? the content of the list? the content of the arrays in the list?

Comment: Yes the content of the list is dynamic and can contain 2 or more byte[] to be  mixed, so i can't declare  :                                                                                                     byte[] source1 = ListAudio.get(0); //first from list
byte[] source2 = ListAudio.get(1); //second from list

Comment: then how is the list filled? when is the list changed?

Comment: The arrayList is filled dynamically in the first For loop of my code. It iterate from audioTreatment.ListDataByte which was filled of sounds produced by different touch on buttons.

Comment: and you want to merge them **all** together?

Comment: Thanks you very much, exactly the process i need. It fail with a indexOutOfBoundsException due to the length. The best is to add 0 to the missing bytes or use Math.min?

Comment: if you want to mix it full length, add 0, that's the very correct way to do!

Comment: Perfect it works, thanks you very much for your help Martin Frank.